# Inheritance concept in java with two sub classes

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

I am curious to know the implementation of following real-life scenario in JAVA.
Lets say,

1. There is an EMPLOYEE class, ENGINEER class and MANAGER class.
2. EMPLOYEE class is super class or parent class of ENGINEER and MANAGER class.

Now on a fine day, ENGINEER got promotion and became MANAGER.
so shall we delete the ENGINEER object and create new MANAGER object for this promoted ENGINEER?
OR what can be the best way to implement it in java?

Comment: It doesn't make sense that `Engineer` or `Manager` are *super* class of `Employee`. And for your question, you can easily construct a new `Manager` from an already existing `Engineer` ;)

Comment: That coud be a solution. Another would be to use delegation instead of inheritance. Each Employee would have a Role, and Role would have two subclasses: Engineer and Manager. When an Engineer, designing and building useful stuff, is downgraded to Manager and passes all his days on Excel time sheets and pointless meetings, he would get a new Role :-)

Comment: In practice, "objects" are relatively short-lived (usually shorter than the lifetime of a program), so the "employee" would be created as *either* a manager or an engineer - the "promotion" wouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you answered your own question. As no two classes are same, you have to delete one object and make another if you are changing an entity from one form to other(Engineer to Manager). Consider the below example for details
Let Employee be the interface. Engineer and Manager classes implements Employee.

```
interface Employee
{
   void attendsMeeting();
   void reportsWorkDone();
   void inputsHoursWorked();
}

class Manager implements Employee
{
   String name;
   int emp_id; //and more fields related to Manager

   public void attendsMeeting()
   {
      //Implements the method
   }
   public void reportsWorkDone()
   {
      //Implements the method
   }
   public void inputsHoursWorked()
   {
      //Implements the method
   }
   public void managesThings()
   {
      //Method specific to Manager class
   }
}

class Engineer implements Employee
{
   String name;
   int emp_id; //and more fields related to Engineer

   public void attendsMeeting()
   {
      //Implements the method
   }
   public void reportsWorkDone()
   {
      //Implements the method
   }
   public void inputsHoursWorked()
   {
      //Implements the method
   }
   public void developsApplication()
   {
      //Method specific to Engineer class
   }
}
```

From the above code, you can see that Engineer and Manager are two different objects. They implemented Employee so they got some common methods that are inherited from Employee. In addition they also got methods that are specific to both the sub classes. Not even the inherited methods in both the classes will have same implementation. So as these two are different objects, you have to delete Engineer object and create a Manager object for a specific Employee(person) if he is promoted.